# Did Jesus ever say that he loved someone in the Bible?

Tags: john, jesus

Jesus asked Peter if he loved him, and Peter affirmed his love for Jesus.

In [John 21:15](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/21/15/t_conc_1018015), it is written,

> So when they had dined, Jesus saith to Simon Peter, Simon, son of Jonas, lovest thou me more than these? He saith unto him, Yea, Lord; thou knowest that I love thee. He saith unto him, Feed my lambs. <sup>**KJV, 1769**</sup>

But, is there any verse in the bible where Jesus himself says that he loves someone (e.g., an apostle, disciple, sinner, etc.)? I am requesting a verse that has a quotation of Jesus.

I realize that the Bible mentions God the Father loving someone, e.g. "the world" ([John 3:16](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/3/16/t_conc_1000016)). I also realize that Jesus is understood to be God the Son. But, I'm searching for a verse wherein Jesus (not God the Father) expresses his love for someone.

Comment: ISTM that this is an example of "seeking for a verse" which is officially against the rules. Hermeneutics is about understanding a given text. It looks though that people have made an exception in your case.

Comment: @SimplyaChristian  I don't have that privilege. I don't give the "right" answers.

Comment: The question is not only about seeking a verse but also why such phrases are rare or not existing

Comment: He didn't have to say it, he showed it. And it was brought by Christ, in its fruition, with The Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 5):

Answer: Yes, it is explicitly mentioned that Jesus loved someone.

In [John 13:23](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/13/1/t_conc_1010023), it is written,

> Now there was one of his disciples reclining on Jesus' bosom, **whom Jesus loved**.
>
> ἦν δέ ἀνακείμενος εἷς τῶν μαθητῶν αὐτοῦ ἐν τῷ κόλπῳ τοῦ Ἰησοῦ **ὃν ἠγάπα ὁ Ἰησοῦς** <sup>**TR, 1550**</sup>

This particular disciple is often referred to as "the beloved disciple."

However, this is not the only occurrence. It is also mentioned that Jesus loved Martha, Mary, and Lazarus (they were siblings).

In [John 11:5](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/11/5/t_conc_1008005), it is written,

> Now Jesus loved Martha, and her sister, and Lazarus.
>
> ἠγάπα δὲ ὁ Ἰησοῦς τὴν Μάρθαν καὶ τὴν ἀδελφὴν αὐτῆς καὶ τὸν Λάζαρον  <sup>**TR, 1550**</sup>

For an actual quote, where Jesus says that he loved someone, I would cite [Rev. 3:9](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/rev/3/9/t_conc_1170009) in which it is written, (*Jesus is speaking*)

> "Behold, I give --- of the synagogue of Satan, who profess themselves to be Jews, and are not, but rather, they lie --- behold, I will make them come and worship before your feet, and to know that I loved you."
>
> ἰδού, διδωμι ἐκ τῆς συναγωγῆς τοῦ Σατανᾶ τῶν λεγόντων ἑαυτοὺς Ἰουδαίους εἶναι καὶ οὐκ εἰσὶν ἀλλὰ ψεύδονται ἰδού, ποιήσω αὐτοὺς ἵνα ἥξωσιν καὶ προσκυνήσωσιν ἐνώπιον τῶν ποδῶν σου καὶ γνῶσιν ὅτι ἐγὼ ἠγάπησά σε <sup>**TR, 1550**</sup>

That is about as close it comes of a verse wherein Jesus is speaking and says he loves someone.

Comment: Ok, but these verses aren't quotes of Himself or are they?

Comment: Something that He has said.

Comment: @SimplyaChristian  I think that is the answer. Should you post it as an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: I've found a text: Joh. 15:9-10. " As the Father has loved me, so have I loved you."